# QGIS WMS URL parameters for zoom / scale?

Tags: wms, qgis-server, qgis-web-client, url

I have a link for WMS in QGIS Server like this:

```
http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&CRS=EPSG:21781&REQUEST=GetMap&map=C:/OSgeo4W/SERVER/SQL.qgs&BBOX=608350,264875,615466,268677&WIDTH=1200&HEIGHT=1300&LAYERS=TS&FILTER=TS:%22ID%22+=+3&FORMAT=image/png&
```

Is there any possibility to give an additional parameter for zooming in URL like:

`zoom-order=n&` or `scale=n&` (not for printing)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [WMS description of the Geoserver website](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getmap) you can see the available parameters.

Scale/zoom are defined by the combination of BBOX and WIDTH/HEIGHT.

Tiled WMS do have different zoom levels, but a normal WMS can serve any any scale (if not restricted by the operators).